# XPath - find lowest elements with specific attribute values

Tags: xml, xpath, conditional-statements

How can I get a list of elements that fit to a certain condition, but are also don't have decedents that fit to the same condition (i.e. the lowest elements in their hierarchy that fit to the condition)?

For instance, consider the following XML:

```
<root>
  <parent1 MyCond='true'>
    <child1 MyCond='false'>
      ...
    </child1>
    <child2 MyCond='true'>
      ...
    </child2>
    <child3 MyCond='false'>
      ...
    </child3>
  </parent1>
  <parent2 MyCond='false'>
    <child1 MyCond='false'>
      ...
    </child1>
    <child2 MyCond='true'>
      ...
    </child2>
  </parent2>
  <parent3 MyCond='true'>
    <child1 MyCond='false'>
      ...
    </child1>
  </parent3>
</root>
```

Using the following XPath expression: `//*[@MyCond='true']` gives `[parent1, parent1/child2, parent2/child2, parent3]`.

I'm looking for a way to filter out `parent1` which has a decedent `parent1/child2` already in the list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the predicate: there is no descendant with the true condition.

```
//*[@MyCond='true'][not(descendant::*[@MyCond='true'])]
```

or, equivalently,

```
//*[@MyCond='true' and not(descendant::*[@MyCond='true'])]
```